# Searching multiple cells in multiple worksheets and then copying another cells value in a summary sheet

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have a workbook that has 4 worksheets all of which have dates on row 5, stating at column D. In the cell next to the date the person will put either 'ET','LT','EG','1ET', '2LT' or they will leave it blank.

I am reading on how VBA works at the moment but I have just started so very new to this.

I have this so far:

```
 Sub test()
     Dim summarySheet As Worksheet
     Dim sh As Worksheet
     Dim j As Integer

        'change "Summary" to the sheet name that is true for you'
        Set summarySheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary")

        'number of first row where need to paste in summary sheet'
        j = 2

       'loop throught all sheets'
       For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
           If sh.Name <> summarySheet.Name Then
               summarySheet.Range("B" & j & ":AF" & j).Value = _
               sh.Range("D5:AH5").Value
               j = j + 1
           End If
        Next
End Sub
```

It displays all the sheets data, but what I need is if there is either ET or LT entered in row 5 next to the date then it adds the corresponding data from row 37 into a summary sheet. If it's just the number then it is to skip that and find the next ET or LT

```
EG
    Sheet 1
Row 5   1ET 2LT 3ET 4 5 6  7ET 8ET         
    ===========================
Row 37  16  32   2         45  67  

Sheet 2

Row 5    1 2  3LT 4ET 5ET 6LT 7 8LT 
         ===========================
Row 37        23  33 13  22     34


    SUMMARY SHEET

        ET  LT
   1    16  
   2        32
   3    2   23
   4    33  
   5    13  
   6        
   7    45  
   8    67  34  
   9        
   Etc
```

Comment: No need for VBA here. A simple IF formula will do - unless you want to put the values there automatically. If so - please show your code this far

Comment: I would like the summary sheet to have values populated automatically

Comment: Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0):

I don't completely understand what you are trying to do.  Your code copies the range exactly to the Summary sheet, but it looks like the result you want transposes them - has the numbers/dates running down the rows instead of across the rows.  Also, you say "dates" but have the numbers 1-9 on the Summary Sheet and have the numbers 1-9 on your Sheet1 and Sheet2.  I also cannot tell which column the "corresponding" values in row 37 are.

Therefore, this code may not exactly work for you as it based on the assumptions that 1) you do NOT want D5:AH5 from each sheet pasted exactly onto the Summary sheet; 2) since they are the only ones you mention as criteria, "ET" and "LT" are the only codes next to "dates" you care about; 3) the value in row 37 is in the same column as the "date"; 4) the "1ET" and "2LT" in your data represent a "1" in D5, "ET" in E5, "2" in F5, "LT" in G5, and so on; 5) since you used the numbers 1-9, the row for pasting the value from row 37 is determined by taking the "date" and adding 1.  If you have actual dates, you will need to change your logic for pasteRow.

```
Sub test()
    Dim summarySheet As Worksheet
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim searchRng As Range
    Dim dateCell As Range
    Dim pasteCol As Integer
    Dim copyRow As Integer
    Dim pasteRow as integer

    'change "Summary" to the sheet name that is true for you'
    Set summarySheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary")

    'the "corresponding row" to copy
    copyRow = 37

    'loop throught all sheets'
    For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If sh.Name <> summarySheet.Name Then
            'set the range that we are using
            Set searchRng = sh.Range("D5:AH5")

            For Each cell In searchRng
                'loop through the range and check if it has the desired key value
                If cell.Value = "ET" Or cell.Value = "LT" Then
                    'set which column on SummarySheet will get the value
                    If cell.Value = "ET" Then
                        'column B, ie column #2
                        pasteCol = 2
                    ElseIf cell.Value = "LT" Then
                        'column C, ie column #3
                        pasteCol = 3
                    End If
                    'set the cell containing the date - assumes is to the left of our key value cell
                    Set dateCell = cell.Offset(0, -1)
                    'set row # to paste to, ie if the value in dateCell is 9, then paste to row 10
                     pasteRow = dateCell.Value + 1
                    'set the value on summarySheet using the value in dateCell + 1 for our row number
                    'and dateCell's column with copyRow to get our "corresponding" value
                    summarySheet.Range(Cells(pasteRow, pasteCol).Address).Value = _
                            sh.Range(Cells(copyRow, dateCell.Column).Address)
               End If
            Next cell
        End If
     Next
End Sub
```

EDITED  based on new information from actual spreadsheet:

```
Sub test()
    Dim summarySheet As Worksheet
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim searchRng As Range
    Dim dateNum As Integer
    Dim pasteCol As Integer
    Dim copyRow As Integer
    Dim pasteRow As Integer
    Dim c As Range
    Dim oldVal As Integer

    'change "Summary" to the sheet name that is true for you'
    Set summarySheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary")
    'clear current value on summarySheet
    summarySheet.Range("C3:D33").Value = ""

    'loop throught all sheets'
    For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If sh.Name <> summarySheet.Name Then
            'set the range that we are using
            Set searchRng = sh.Range("D5:AH5")

            'the "corresponding row" to copy
            With sh.Range("C:C")
                Set c = .Find("Number of staff")
                If Not c Is Nothing Then
                    copyRow = c.Row
                End If
            End With

            For Each cell In searchRng
                'loop through the range and check if it has the desired key value
                If cell.Value Like "*ET" Or cell.Value Like "*LT" Then
                    'set which column on SummarySheet will get the value
                    If cell.Value Like "*ET" Then
                        'column C, so column #3
                        pasteCol = 3
                    ElseIf cell.Value Like "*LT" Then
                        'column D, so column #4
                        pasteCol = 4
                    End If
                    'get the date from the cell
                    dateNum = Val(cell.Value)
                    If dateNum = 0 Then
                        MsgBox "Sheet " & sh.Name & " cell " & cell.Address & " is missing date.  Please fill in and run again."
                        Exit Sub
                    End If
                    'set row # to paste to, ie if the value in dateCell is 9, then paste to row 11
                     pasteRow = dateNum + 2
                    'set the value on summarySheet using cell's column with copyRow to get our "corresponding" value
                    oldVal = summarySheet.Range(Cells(pasteRow, pasteCol).Address).Value
                    summarySheet.Range(Cells(pasteRow, pasteCol).Address).Value = _
                            sh.Range(Cells(copyRow, cell.Column).Address).Value + oldVal
               End If
            Next cell
        End If
     Next
     MsgBox "Complete"
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello I am not sure what you mean, I tried your code and it doesn't seem to work.  If you want to see the actual spreadsheet the please feel free to look at it at https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByFZXfbrqq2KZ21KXzY0dTlZd0k

Comment: Yup, you had the key in the same cell instead of next to it, the data on "Summary" is in a different location that what I had assumed, and the "Number of Staff" was only in row 37 on the first two tabs.  I have updated my answer for those events as well as added a message box warning for when the date doesn't have the date, as was the case for 26 on three of the sheets.  If you're going to use VBA, you need to either have consistent formatting or a logical way to determine what your information is or where to find it.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Option Explicit
 Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
 Dim r As Range, rng As Range, snRow As Range, x As Integer
 ActiveSheet.Range("C4:AG5").ClearContents
 For x = 1 To Sheets.Count
If Sheets(x).Name <> "Summary" Then
    With Sheets(Sheets(x).Name)
        With .Range("C:C")
            Set snRow = .Find("Number of staff", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
        End With
        Set rng = .Range("D5", "AH5")
        For Each r In rng
            If InStr(1, r.Value, "LT") > 0 Then
                Sheets("Summary").Cells(5, r.Column - 1) = .Cells(snRow.Row, r.Column).Value
            ElseIf InStr(1, r.Value, "ET") > 0 Then
                Sheets("Summary").Cells(4, r.Column - 1) = .Cells(snRow.Row, r.Column).Value
            End If
        Next
    End With
End If
Next
End Sub
```

This achieves everything I wanted with the summary sheet going across the page instead of vertically.